# "Gradle projects"-section not appearing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, mobile, cross-platform

I am trying to update to Java 11 in android-studio for a flutter project. All resources ask me go to *'File=>settings=>Build, Execution, Deployment =>Gradle'*.

Then on left side should be a section called "Gradle projects", but I do not have this section:

[image]

How I can show this section?

Comment: restart studio or invalidate cache

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI  its not worked